# Improving equation algorithm ax+by=c with the smallest difference between |x-y|

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, equation

I am struggling for quite a while to improve my algorithm but with no progress.

I need a reusable function to calculate `x*3+y*5=n`.

**Constrains:**

- n>=7
- x,y,n always  whole positive integer numbers
- i need to find the combination with the most minimal distance between x and y 
  (in absolute value) `|x-y|`

that is a console app draft i have written, it compiles and work but, as you can see, very not efficient when dealing with large numbers.

i think i have a lack of knowledge in math in order to improve that code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetWarAfterMath(5000000);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

const int FIRST = 3;
const int SECOND = 5;

static void GetWarAfterMath(int n)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int delta = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if ((i * FIRST) + (j * SECOND) == n)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(i + "*" + FIRST + "+" + j + "*" + SECOND + "=" + n);
                if (Math.Abs(i - j) < delta)
                {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                    delta = Math.Abs(x - y);
                }
                break;
            }

            else if ((j * FIRST) + (i * SECOND) == n)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(j + "*" + FIRST + "+" + i + "*" + SECOND + "=" + n);
                if (j - i < delta)
                {
                    x = j;
                    y = i;
                    delta = Math.Abs(x - y);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("THE WINNERS ARE:" + x + "*" + FIRST + "+" + y + "*" + SECOND + "=" + n);
}
```

**EDIT:**

---

finally after combining @Yves Daoust, @user3386109 and @Hasson answers.
 time complexity decreased dramatically,
 Execution time with the number 8000000: 127 miliseconds!
this is the final algorithm:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetMatch(34);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

const double FIRST = 3;
const double SECOND = 5;

static void GetMatch(double n)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int finalX = 0;
    int finalY = int.MaxValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < n / FIRST; i++)
    {
        if (((n - FIRST * i) / SECOND) % 1 == 0)
        {
            y = Convert.ToInt32(((n - FIRST * i) / SECOND));
            x = i;
            if(Math.Abs(x-y) < Math.Abs(finalX-finalY))
            {
                finalX = x;
                finalY = y;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("THE WINNERS ARE:" + finalX + "*" + FIRST + "+" + finalY + "*" + SECOND + "=" + n + "    Calc: " +  (finalX * FIRST + finalY * SECOND));
}
```

Note that as @Yves Daoust wrote in his first answer its also possible to solve this with inear diophantine equation using the Euclidian Algorithm but you need to reverse the Euclidian Algorithm, I preferred to keep it simple.
here is a nice video about that topic with a solution, if somebody intrested:
Number Theory: [Diophantine Equation: ax+by=gcd(a,b)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjliV5u2IVw)

thank you very much for the help.

Comment: when you write x and y are integer you mean only integers or positive integers ?

Comment: yes positive, i have updated the question.

Comment: So does your code not work as expected? Or what is a problem? "Improve" is quite generic term.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code reviews belong on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Evk if you will run that code with n=500000 you can go and make your self a cup of coffee and after you will finish to drink it the execution will finish.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it does not belong to code review because its not working as if you put large numbers it takes centuries to complete. we don't consider that a working code. so any optimization by code review is not going to help OP what so ever

Comment: maybe this is something that relates to math. if you know the term. currently you are going a brute force approach which is indeed slow

Comment: A little bit of algebra will show you that (x-y) is equal to ((FIRST + SECOND) * x - n) / SECOND. The minimum value of this can be zero, so you are looking for all values where n = (FIRST + SECOND) * x, which result in y being an integer. So loop through all x, which give n > 7 (or required value) & check result of y = (n - FIRST *x) / SECOND being an integer.

Comment: BTW, the first constraint should be `n > 7`. There is no solution for `7`.

Comment: Are you sure you have the equation right - the minimum of x-y is zero, so achieved when x = y, so all you need is to find when substituting (FIRST + SECOND) * x, you get a result greater than 7 - with the constraint of x being a positive integer, this is all values in your example.

Comment: @PaulF: x == y only works when n is a multiple of 8.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: as I read the question OP is looking for the combination of x,y, **AND** n to minimise |x-y| - if it is required to only find the combination of x & y for specific values of n then the question needs clarifying as others seem to have read it the same and answered on that basis. If you are correct then yours is a very good answer & I have upvoted accordingly.

Comment: @PaulF: this would trivially be x=1, y=1, n=8. the answer by user3386109 is equally good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem `ax+by = c` is very well-known in number theory (it is a linear diophantine equation).

It can only have a solution if `gcd(3,5)|n`, which is of course always true.

Then, if you know some solution to `3x°+5y°=n`, all solutions are of the form `x=x°-5k`, `y=y°+3k`.

It is very easy to find a solution, as one of `n`, `n-5`, `n-10` is certainly a multiple of `3`.

All that remains is to minimize `|x°-5k-y°-3k|` under the constraints `x°-5k>0`, `y°+3k>0`. The minimum will be achieved by the value of `8k` the closest to `x°-y°`, or the value that saturates one of the constraints.

For instance, for `n=173000`, `x°=57665` and `y°=1` is a solution. Then `k=(57665-1)/8=7208` yields `|x-y|=0`. This solution is acceptable because the constraints are fulfilled.

---

I am not providing full details of the case study, but the main lesson is: no loop required !

Comment: if i could i would upvote more that once. thank you! - for future readers i will publish the final algorithm in my original answer. thanks again.

Comment: @jonathana: actually the constraints are always fulfilled (except maybe for tiny values of n ?) and you shouldn't worry. If I am right, the optimal solution in k is one or two units from n/24.

Answer (score 5):

The goal is to minimize `|x-y|`. So start with `y=x` and solve the equation

```
3x + 5x = n
   8x = n
```

If `n` is a multiple of 8, then you've found an integer solution.

Otherwise, try `y=x+1`

```
3x + 5(x+1) = n
  8x + 5 = n
```

If `n-5` is a multiple of 8, then you've found an integer solution.

Otherwise, try it the other way around

```
3(y+1) + 5y = n
  8y + 3 = n
```

If `n-3` is a multiple of 8, then you've found integer solution.

Rinse and repeat to get the following results

```
|x-y|==0 works if n is a multiple of 8
|x-y|==1 works if (n-3) or (n-5) is a multiple of 8
|x-y|==2 works if (n-2) or (n-6) is a multiple of 8
|x-y|==3 works if (n-1) or (n-7) is a multiple of 8
|x-y|==4 works if (n-4) is a multiple of 8
```

At least one of those conditions must be true, so `|x-y|` will always be less than or equal to 4.

Comment: Do you account for the fact that both x and y are positive?

Comment: @Evk: x=y, so the solution is valid for all x>0 where x is multiple of 8 (or sum of the two multipliers to make the solution "Reusable").

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to loop for both x and y, this is a simple equation where you know n, so if you consider x = 1..n , then you can calculate y = (n-3*x)/5 and test if it is integer or not (even better you can test if n-3*x ends with 5 or 0 or not, if it is then this is a valid combination otherwise it is not. So over all it is one loop, and I think we can add more optimization.

And by the way delta has to be initialized with very large number, or n for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an efficient algorithm, then start with the solution in real values (e.g. double or float) for x == y. Then round x to the next integer and take that as starting point. Test for the next few pairs (x,y) of integers only. Break when your delta becomes worse.

Comment: I am not sure this works. The target function |x - y| might be non monotonic and its minimum far from the initial estimate.

Comment: Of course you have to test ALL pairs in the vicinity of the real solution. And yes, vicinity is a quite relative wording. But if you find a valid integer solution, say with a delta of s, you only have to check  for pairs with |x-y| < s.

Comment: my point is that a valid integer solution may lie far from the real solution x==y and the "vicinity" could be the whole domain.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But that's no contradiction to my argument. Imagine all pairs, which fullfill the solution as a 2D map. Now you have to find the one with the minimum distance. If you find ANY pair, you have to go on with testing, but only for the remaining pairs with smaller distance, And yes, you may end up close to the border of the domain. If thats the case, this algorithm is not that much faster. But in most cases it will be.

Comment: Very sorry, I misread the problem statement (** instead of *). Please disregard all my comments).

Answer (score 0):

Though my other solution has been accepted, there is an even simpler approach.

If rationals are allowed, you always achieve the minimum `0` with `x = y = n / 8`. With the restriction on integers, `x = y = floor(n / 8)` yields `|x - y| = n mod 8`, which is one of `0..7`. You can adjust by adding/subtracting `5` from `x` while subtracting/adding `3` to `y`, and you only have to solve the problem for `n` in `0..7`.